# How to make Python code to transform data in power BI more efficient to reduce refresh time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powerbi, powerquery

I am currently using .apply and if statement to create a conditional column returning string values based on other columns in a power BI table. These conditions are to categorize data in a way that considers incorrectly entered data. The code returns exactly the result I want but is slow, the table is about 50,000 rows and the if statement is being run over every row.  Here is my code:

```py
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fd = dataset[pd.isnull(dataset['bID'])]["RepackaID"].dropna().tolist()

def conditions(x):

    if pd.notnull(x['bID']) and pd.notnull(x["RepackaID"]):
        return 'b Input'
    elif x['bID'] == 0:
        return 'b Input'
# Below is the line that I struggled to do in power query M
    elif pd.notnull(x['aID']) and x['aID'] in fd:
        return "a Repack Output"
    elif x["Repack"] == True:
        return "b Repack Output"
    elif pd.notnull(x["bID"]):
        return "b Traded"
    elif x['cID'] == 94 or x['cID'] == 41:
        return "b Repack Output"
    elif pd.notnull(x["RepackaID"]):
        return "a Repack Input"
    else:
        return "a Output"

dataset['new column'] = dataset.apply(conditions, axis=1)
```

The line I struggled to do in power query M is marked with a comment it references the list fd defined above. It is just a case of returning this result "a repack output" to our new column if a value for aID exists in RepackaID butdoing this over 50,000 rows. The rest seems quiet easy to implement in power query m.

Just wondering if I am doing this in the most pythonic way (I suspect not) or if there is a better way to do this in m power query, any ideas? I would actually prefer to do this in m power query as other people working on this don't use python. Any improvements would be much welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

In Python pandas, always aim for vectorized operations and avoid running rowwise operations with `for ... iterrows` or `.apply` (often a hidden loop). Specifically, for multiple conditional statements, consider [**`numpy.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) that conditionally assigns elementwise between an equal number list of conditions and list of values all with whole arrays and not individual cells.

```py
fd = dataset[pd.isnull(dataset['bID'])]["RepackaID"].dropna().tolist()

# LIST OF BOOLEAN ARRAYS
conditions = [
    (pd.notnull(dataset['bID'])) & (pd.notnull(dataset["RepackaID"])),
    dataset['bID'] == 0,
    (pd.notnull(dataset['aID'])) & (dataset['aID'].isin(fd)),
    dataset["Repack"] == True,
    pd.notnull(dataset["bID"]),
    (dataset['cID'] == 94) | (dataset['cID'] == 41),
    pd.notnull(dataset["RepackaID"])
]

# LIST OF RETURN VALUES
values = [
    "b Input",
    "b Input",
    "a Repack Output",
    "b Repack Output",
    "b Traded",
    "b Repack Output".
    "a Repack Input"
]

dataset['new column'] = np.select(conditions, values, default="a Output")
```